# how to compute norm.ppf() in tensorflow/Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normal-distribution

I want to use inverse of cumulative distribution function (cdf)  which can be done using norm.ppf() from scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm
inside a layer of a tf/keras model architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Normal#quantile), `tfp.distribution.Normal` does have a method for calculating ppf (percent point function). It's called `quantile`:

```
scipy.stats.norm(loc=0, scale=1).ppf(0.95)
```

Output:

```
1.6448536269514722
```

Tensorflow:

```
tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=0, scale=1).quantile(0.95)
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.6448536>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I was looking for ppf or percent point function in the titles.